# Why does assertRedirects() expect a string rather than a URL?

Tags: django, django-testing

Why does these two asserts work:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy('create_cm')) 
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('upload_booth'))
        self.assertRedirects(response, str(reverse_lazy('upload_booth')))
```

but this doesn't:

```
self.assertRedirects(response, reverse_lazy('upload_booth'))
```

instead producing this error message:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py",
>   line 300, in assertRedirects
>       e_query, e_fragment))
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 234, in urlunsplit
>       url = '//' + (netloc or '') + url TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, **proxy** found

What exactly is the difference in return values from reverse and reverse_lazy, and why are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementations of lazy functions **do not** return the value directly on instantiation, instead return a proxy object. As a specific call to this object happens its real value gets evaluated and returned.

In case of `reverse_lazy` you can see this in your own example:

```
str(reverse_lazy('upload_booth'))
```

This is a call to the proxy object's `__str__` method and then really returns a string instead of a proxy object.

All implementation details can be found at the [Django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/urls/base/#reverse)